# Is there a single documentation page for all the XDG_* environment variables?

Tags: freedesktop, xdg

I can find documentation for *some* XDG_* here and there, but for many others I still don't know where to look.

I have not been able to find a single document where the meaning of all these variables is spelled out (or at least a reference thereto is provided).

Does such documentation exist?

Comment: Have you checked [this reference to the freedesktop standards page](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/ar01s03.html). It looks to cover most of them.

Comment: @Patesh: that page is a good example of what I've been finding; it defines some variables, but most of the XDG_* variables that are (somehow) getting set in my environment are not mentioned in this document.